# Write selected area to file

Tags: save

I'd like to write a visually selected area to a file.

For example:

```
prefix [sample text
more text] suffix
```

`[]` is the selected block which should be taken, resulting in a new file containing:

```
sample text
more text
```

The normal `w` command uses lines so `'<,'>w! /tmp/test` would include the prefix/suffix (and `` `<,`>w! /tmp/test `` is not allowed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7720520/14555505

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, copy (also called 'yank' in vim parlance) your visual selection to the register of your choice. For example, to copy to register 'z', make your visual selection, and then type `"zy`.

In the case you give, you could do this without moving the cursor, by putting the cursor on the first square brace, and then typing `v%"zy`.

Breakdown: `v` -> start visual selection; `%` -> move to matching brace; `"z` -> use register 'z'; `y` -> yank (copy) the selection (in this case, into register 'z').

Once you have copied your visual selection to register 'z', go to the command line, and type

```
call writefile(getreg('z', 1, 1), "some-file")
```

If you want to append the text, rather than overwrite, you can use the "a" flag as follows

```
call writefile(getreg('z', 1, 1), "some-file", "a")
```

Comment: So that means there is no builtin command that can do this?

Comment: @laktak Not that I could find ... A `split()`? `getreg(.., 1, 1)` returns a list, so a `split()` isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks - you are too fast :) I just realized my mistake and edited the comment while you responded.

Answer (score 3):

You can also copy your content and create a new window

```
Ctrl-w n ........... create a new window
p .................. paste
```

Then you can save as you want

Answer (score 2):

1. Vim help says (:h 10.3):

> Note:
> **When using Visual mode to select part of a line, or using CTRL-V to
> select a block of text, the colon commands will still apply to whole
> lines.**  This might change in a future version of Vim.

2. The plugin [**vis** (#1195)](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) by Charles Campbell offers the command `:B {cmd}` to apply a `{cmd}` only to the visual (block) selection.

Comment: I've just tried to implement this approach to make a mapping so that <C-c> copies the selected text to the Mac clipboard: `vnoremap <C-c> :B w !pbcopy<CR><CR>`. This doesn't work. Am I using the `vis` syntax incorrectly?

Comment: Blockwise yanking to clipboard should be possible without a colon command with `"+y`. No plugin necessary. Are you using neovim?

Comment: That worked, thank you! (Yes, I am using neovim.) I didn't know about this feature. Is there a similar mapping for the inverse procedure, to paste from the clipboard? Or is that something I should add to my `.vimrc` myself?

Comment: Or I suppose one can simply enter INSERT mode and press Command-V (on a Mac). But perhaps there is a more `vim`ish way to do this?

Comment: Pasting from clipboard should be possible with `"+p` in normal mode and in insert mode with `<c-r>+`. If you like standard macOS shortcuts `Cmd+x`, `Cmd+c`, `Cmd+v` in normal and insert mode, have a look into https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/master/runtime/macmap.vim#L48-L57 Afaik, they do not exist in vim/neovim by default. A quick test of the [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/master/runtime/macmap.vim#L48-L57) mappings in [VimR  (neovim GUI)](https://github.com/qvacua/vimr)  worked for me.

Comment: That worked (`"+p` I mean). Thank you!